# Reloading route after .save()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to reload a route after a `.save()` (in controller). Currently, ember-data is changing the status in the store but whatever I tried for reloading the route didn't work. The problem is I want to reload the current route based on conversation status.

For example, if I'm currently in `status=opened` and I close the conversation, I want to reload the route `status=opened`. I noticed that because the status param doesn't change, the route is not reloaded!

I tried doing a `this.store.find('conversation', { status : currentStatus })`, but it doesn't work.

How can I do this? I can edit for more details if needed.

I have this model hook :

```
model: function(params){

    return this.store.find('conversation', { status : params.status});

},

queryParams: {

    status: {
        refreshModel: true
    }
}
```

When I want to change the status a conversation, I'm using the following :

```
this.store.find('conversation', conv.id).then(function(conversation){
                conversation.set('status', 'closed');
                conversation.save();            
});
```

Comment: Can't you just call "refresh()" on the router

Comment: From my controller? Because that's where I'm using the save method. What is the correct syntax for this if you don't mind?

Comment: You'd write directly that you save in controller. It is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the filter both server and client side, and then you don't need to reload the route, it'll be much cheaper.

```
model: function(params){
    return this.store.filter('conversation', { status : params.status}, function(rec){
       return rec.get('status') === params.status;
    });
},
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter

Comment: typo, should be: `return (rec.get('status') === params.status);`

Comment: YOU JUST SAVED MY LIFE. Thank you, I really don't think the docs explain this situation correctly.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to know what to and not to use when there is so much functionality.